# Dimension reduction:T-SNE, PCA are not preserving the Euclidean distance

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, computer-vision, pca

My data exists in 128 dimensions, I'trying to reduce my data to 3 dimensions to visualize my data and preserve the Euclidean distance. Then distance represent the similarity between two data points.

Original data X: 5 * 128 (5 data points)

```
[[ -4.46e-02   1.57e-01   2.17e-01   1.24e-01   6.01e-02   7.61e-02
    6.38e-02  -1.05e-01  -2.55e-02   5.99e-02  -8.38e-02   5.93e-02
   -1.58e-01  -1.05e-01   1.31e-01  -5.33e-02  -4.18e-02   9.32e-02
   -1.62e-02  -9.19e-02  -1.30e-01   8.56e-02  -6.13e-02   3.78e-02
    7.84e-02  -9.74e-02  -9.42e-02   7.47e-02  -4.65e-02   7.36e-03
   -9.19e-04   1.37e-01  -8.52e-02   9.27e-02   6.50e-02  -2.61e-02
    7.21e-02  -1.83e-01  -2.49e-02  -9.85e-03   1.57e-01  -7.98e-02
    1.50e-01  -1.40e-01  -2.39e-02   4.19e-02   6.98e-02  -1.27e-02
   -7.56e-02   4.44e-02   1.86e-01  -2.22e-03  -1.79e-02  -3.90e-02
    7.72e-02   4.47e-02  -8.15e-02  -4.31e-02  -6.52e-03   7.73e-02
   -1.37e-02   5.78e-02  -1.25e-01  -1.58e-01   1.37e-01   9.34e-02
   -6.07e-03  -1.69e-01  -2.12e-01   2.14e-01  -4.05e-02   1.29e-01
    4.42e-02   1.71e-01  -2.13e-02   8.00e-03   7.17e-02   4.57e-03
   -6.55e-03  -1.66e-01   3.73e-02   1.01e-01  -1.26e-03   1.96e-02
    5.44e-02  -1.04e-01  -5.32e-02  -1.57e-02  -6.31e-02   1.89e-01
    2.43e-02   1.59e-02   9.13e-03  -4.41e-02  -5.96e-03   1.03e-01
    4.33e-02  -3.94e-02   7.85e-02   3.61e-02  -2.32e-02   3.69e-03
   -9.57e-03  -1.47e-02   2.61e-02  -4.15e-04   1.41e-02  -4.22e-02
   -7.42e-02   1.07e-01   9.08e-03   3.45e-02   6.41e-02  -5.37e-02
    1.57e-02  -1.91e-01   8.21e-02   3.31e-02   3.57e-02   1.37e-02
    1.56e-01   6.25e-02   4.54e-02  -1.07e-02   1.08e-01   2.69e-02
    9.57e-02  -1.24e-01]
...
]
```

Original distance matrix dist:

```
dist = DataArray(squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean')))

[[ 0.  ,  0.67,  0.62,  0.7 ,  0.67],
 [ 0.67,  0.  ,  0.48,  0.76,  0.46],
 [ 0.62,  0.48,  0.  ,  0.7 ,  0.48],
 [ 0.7 ,  0.76,  0.7 ,  0.  ,  0.6 ],
 [ 0.67,  0.46,  0.48,  0.6 ,  0.  ]]
```

**T-SNE**:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

model = TSNE(n_components=3, random_state=0)
x_tsne = model.fit_transform(x)
```

x_tsne:

```
[[  1.78e-04   4.02e-05   1.01e-04]
 [  2.25e-04   1.90e-04  -1.00e-04]
 [  9.43e-05  -1.72e-05  -1.21e-05]
 [  4.02e-05   1.36e-05   1.49e-04]
 [  7.44e-05   1.08e-05   4.45e-05]]
```

dist_tsne:

```
[[  0.00e+00,   2.55e-04,   1.52e-04,   1.49e-04,   1.22e-04],
   [  2.55e-04,   0.00e+00,   2.60e-04,   3.57e-04,   2.75e-04],
   [  1.52e-04,   2.60e-04,   0.00e+00,   1.72e-04,   6.62e-05],
   [  1.49e-04,   3.57e-04,   1.72e-04,   0.00e+00,   1.10e-04],
   [  1.22e-04,   2.75e-04,   6.62e-05,   1.10e-04,   0.00e+00]]
```

I compares dist and dist_tsne, I noticed that the values are not same, and they are not even proportional. How can I preserve the Euclidean distance while reduce the dimension?

Answer (score 0):

That's theoretically not possible in general.

Your original data is living in much more dimensions and you can't throw away some of them while retaining the distances.

An example:

- Imagine the 3 points of an equilateral triangle (in 2d-space)

  - Every pair of points has the same distance
- Try to map this to a 1-dimensional sequence (number line)

  - It's not possible to keep the pairwise distances

The task of T-SNE and others is: map these point to some lower-dimensional space while keeping the distances **visually** so that we humans grasp some information hidden in many dimensions.

Comment: I've heard the curse of dimensionality. When your features grow, the worse clustering performance you will have. However, the clustering is based on the distance matrix. If I'm not able to reduce the dimensions(PCA) while preserving the distance, how would dimension reduction would improve the clustering performance?

Comment: @BooYaah My example is not much about the curse of dimensionality. The CoD can always be beaten in theory using more data/time. The example above will always be impossible (given the definitions). I don't know where you got your idea of pre-embedding before clustering and what you expect. This kind of embedding is another form of clustering itself and loses information (as explained above) before you cluster again. Also you are changing the difference-metric. T-SNE is tuned to give some good representation for *our eyes*, but the shift in data it's doing will probably worsen every alg after.